# Changing IP Address of Windows 2008R2 OS Cluster

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ip, windows-server-2008-r2

We need to change VLAN of our DB Servers.

What steps i should take to change IP address of OS cluster ( Windows Server 2008 R2), which also has SQL Server 2008 R2 DB cluster?
What are the Risks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No risks, only downtime.Change the ips on each node.  Change the DNS entries to the new ips. And open failover cluster from server manager on one of the servers and change the ip addresses. Changing the node name is a bigger issue than changing the ip addresss.